# Java running to slow

Tags: java

I'm trying to execute my java code but it says it's taking too long. Theres a method that pops up saying to check if i have an infinite loop. I don't. At least, I don't think I do. I'm new to java so I really need help. My assignment requires a for loop and this is the code I came up with

```
import java.lang.Math;
public class Main{
  double initialBalance;
  double interestRate;
  double years;
  double totalPayment;
  double firstInterest;
  double lastInterest;
  double totalInterest;
  double totalPrincipal;
  double firstPrincipal;
  double lastPrincipal;
  double firstBalance;
  double lastBalance;
  double monthlyPayment;

  public static final double periodsPerYear = 12;
  public static final double invalidNum = -1.0;

  public Main(double balance, double interest, double Life){
    initialBalance = balance;
    interestRate = interest;
    years = Life;

    //monthlyPayment calculation
    monthlyPayment = initialBalance * ((interestRate/periodsPerYear)+((interestRate/periodsPerYear)/(Math.pow(1+(interestRate/periodsPerYear),periodsPerYear*years)-1)));

    for (double i=0;i<periodsPerYear*years;i++){
      interest = (interestRate/periodsPerYear) * initialBalance;
      totalInterest += interest;

      double principal = monthlyPayment - interest;
      totalPrincipal += principal;

      initialBalance = initialBalance - principal;


      //if statement
      if(i==0){
        firstInterest = interest;
        firstPrincipal = principal;
        firstBalance = initialBalance;
        }
      if(i== (12*2)-1){
        lastInterest = interest;
        lastPrincipal = principal;
        lastBalance = initialBalance;
        }
    }
    totalPayment = totalPrincipal + totalInterest;
  }

  double getMonthlyPayment(){
    return monthlyPayment;
  }

  double getAmount(String month, String type){
    if (month.equals("first")&&type.equals("balance")){
      valid = firstBalance;
    }
    else if (month.equals("first")&&type.equals("interest")){
      valid = firstInterest;
    }
    else if (month.equals("first")&&type.equals("principal")){
      valid = firstPrincipal;
    }
    else if (month.equals("last")&&type.equals("balance")){
      valid = lastBalance0;
    }
    else if (month.equals("last")&&type.equals("interest")){
      valid = lastInterest;
    }
    else if (month.equals("last")&&type.equals("principal")){
      valid = lastPrincipal;
    }
    else{
      valid = invalidNum;
    }
    return Math.round((valid *100.00)/100.00);
  }

  double getTotalInterest(){
    return totalInterest;
  }

  double getTotalPayments(){
    return totalPayment;
  }


  public static void main(String[] args){
        double initialBalance = 10_000.0;
    double interestRate = 0.05;
    double years = 2;

    Main loan = new Main( initialBalance, interestRate, years );
    System.out.println( loan.getMonthlyPayment() );
    System.out.println( loan.getTotalInterest() );
    System.out.println( loan.getTotalPayments() );
    System.out.println( loan.getAmount( "first", "interest" ) );
    System.out.println( loan.getAmount( "first", "principal" ) );
    System.out.println( loan.getAmount( "first", "balance" ) );
    System.out.println( loan.getAmount( "first", "!@#$%^&*()" ) );
    System.out.println( loan.getAmount( "last", "interest" ) );
    System.out.println( loan.getAmount( "last", "principal" ) );
    System.out.println( loan.getAmount( "last", "balance" ) );
    System.out.println( loan.getAmount( "last", "{}|:<>?" ) );
    System.out.println( loan.getAmount( "{)*(&EPQWR", "interest") );
  }
}
```

what could i do to make it execute faster? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try use debug here: double i=0;i<periodsPerYear*years;i++ and check what is going on. Also try use int instead of double.

Comment: The code doesn't compile

Comment: May I suggest that you print out i in your loop.

Comment: You never assign a  value to years. It's a near infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the code you provided does not compile. The variables  'valid' and 'lastBalance0' in getAmount() are not declared. Probably you have forgotten to declare 'double valid' at the top of this method and typed 'lastBalance0' instead of just 'lastBalance'.

There are also some other problems with your code:

- change type of variable 'i' to 'int' in the for loop
- change return Math.round((valid *100.00)/100.00) to return Math.round(valid*100.00)/100.00
- consider using "first".equals(month) instead of month.equals("first"), because it doesn't throw NullPointerException if month is null.

Answer (score 0):

As Alex points out, your code does not compile.

After fixing these 2 things, it did run:

- declare variable double
- fix typo lastBalance0 to lastBalance

The code ran and this is the output:

```
Mon Feb 24 09:34:37 CET 2020
1582533277204
4387.13897340686
5291.335361764231
105291.33536176465
417.0
3970.0
96030.0
-1.0
18.0
4369.0
0.0
-1.0
-1.0
Mon Feb 24 09:34:37 CET 2020
1582533277206
```

I added a print of current date and time in millis at start and end and the program took 2 ms to execute.